# Vue component as child of another component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on converting an existing theme into reusable components.

I currently have a button component like so:

```
<template>
    <a :href="link" class="button" :class="styling"><slot></slot></a>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        link: {},
        styling: {
            default: ''
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And, in my HTML, I use it like so:

```
<vue-button link="#" styling="tiny bg-aqua">Button 1</vue-button>
```

Now, I am attempting to create a "button group" using the existing button component.

What I would like to be able to do is something like this:

```
<vue-button-group styling="radius tiny">
    <vue-button link="#" styling="tiny bg-aqua">Button 1</vue-button>
    <vue-button link="#" styling="tiny bg-aqua">Button 2</vue-button>
    <vue-button link="#" styling="tiny bg-aqua">Button 3</vue-button>
    <vue-button link="#" styling="tiny bg-aqua">Button 4</vue-button>
</vue-button-group>
```

I am very new to VueJS, and am a bit confused on the proper way to handle such a thing. I would like to be able to pass as many button components into the group as is needed.

Here is what I have so far for the button group:

```
<template>
    <ul class="button-group" :class="styling">
        <li><slot></slot></li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            styling: {
                default: ''
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This would, of course, work with a single button being passed in, but I cannot seem to figure out how to allow for more than that, while encasing each button within its own list item.

Any suggestions or corrections to the way I am going about this would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: as a side not, you don't need to pass `styling="tiny bg-aqua"` classes are bound automatically, so using `class="tiny bg-aqua"` has the same result

Comment: also there may be several ways to handle this (slots, named Slots, props), the best solution will depend on how you structure your data, and what your desired end result is.

Comment: @Daniel You are 100% correct. I didn't realize you could use the "class" attribute on a Vue component without overwriting the base classes included in the component by default.

Comment: Got it, I misunderstood the question

Comment: This isn't exactly straight forward with Vue. I would suggest using render functions, but they're not exactly beginner friendly. I would suggest that if this is something you can solve with css, that may be easier to implement and maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to do advanced things with the output of your component, this might be the time to go to [render functions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html), as they allow far more flexibility:

```js
Vue.component('button-group', {
    props: {
        styling: {
            default: ''
        }
    },
    render(createElement) { // createElement is usually called `h`
        // You can also do this in 1 line, but that is more complex to explain...
        // const children = this.$slots.default.filter(slot => slot.tag).map(slot => createElement('li', {}, [slot]))
        const children = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < this.$slots.default.length; i++) {
            if(!this.$slots.default[i].tag) {
                // Filter out "text" nodes, so we don't make li elements
                // for the enters between the buttons
                continue;
            }
            children.push(createElement('li', {}, [
                this.$slots.default[i]
            ]));
        }

        return createElement('ul', {staticClass: "button-group",class: this.styling}, children);
    }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

```css
.rainbow-background {
    /* todo: implement rainbow background */
    border: red 1px solid;
}
.button-group {
    border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <button-group styling="rainbow-background">
        <button>hi</button>
        <button>How are you?</button>
        <button>I'm fine</button>
        <button>Have a nice day!</button>
    </button-group>
</div>
```

A render function works by returning an virtual html structure, this structure is generated by repeated calls to a `createElement` functions. [`createElement`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments) accepts 3 parameters, a tag name (like `ul` or `li`), an options object, and an list of children.

We first start by generating a list of children with our incoming slots, who are stored inside `this.$slots.default`.

Then we loop over this list, filtering out incoming slot data that is basically text, this is because the way HTML considers whitespace between tags as text.

We are now almost complete with our final structure, we now wrap the slot element in a freshly generated `li` tag, and then we finish the generating of with wrapping everything in a new `ul` tag with the proper class names.

Comment: ha, beat me to it... anyway, here is a link to a codesandbox of the renderFunction solution https://codesandbox.io/s/o1qkrvmq4z (minus handling of text nodes)

Comment: This is definitely more advanced than what I was anticipating, but it does work as needed. Thank you for the answer + explanation. I will definitely look more into render functions for the future.

Comment: @Daniel You still shown/teach me that you don't have to worry about those text nodes when using `.vue` files, I just happen to find that they were annoying when I started using html templates for this answer. But adding a filter in for those prevents bad surises when you suddenly switch environments  where you code Vue

Answer (score 1):

The Vue way to do this is use names slots, and provide the data the child uses to the parent.  The data will propagate to the child via the `slot-scope`.

The whole key to this is *the data flows through the parent to the child*.

Here's a working codepen of the process: https://codepen.io/Flamenco/pen/ZMOdYz

This example uses the default slot, so `name` attribute is not needed on parent or child.

## Parent

```
<template>
    <ul class="button-group" :class="styling">
        <li v-for='item in items'><slot :item='item'></slot></li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
   ...
   props:{
      items: Array
   }
</script>
```

## Child

```
<vue-button-group class="radius tiny" :items='items'>
    <template slot-scope='scope'>
       <vue-button link="#" styling="tiny bg-aqua">{{scope.item.text}}</vue-button>
   </template>
</vue-button-group>


<script>
   ...
   data:{
      items:[{text:'Button 1'},{text:'Button 2'},{text:'Button 3}]
   }
</script>
```

Comment: What does this approach bring to the table in contrast to doing the looping in the button group component itself?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for that is to use [v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Component).

```
<button v-for="button in buttons" :key="button">
Button{{button}}
</button>
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dabzj7h0/).

From there you could build your `<buttongroup>`-component yourself; passing "meta-infos" into your `<buttongroup>` as [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) (in my fiddle the array in the `data`-part).

[Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#ad) would make sense, if you want to render something else besides the buttons and you want to inject components for that. Otherwise you would gain nothing with slots.

Comment: Apologies, but I am having a hard time understanding how the v-for would work in this instance; without hardcoding the number of buttons into the component itself (like in your fiddle).

Comment: you could, as I said pass an array from the parent as props and your button group iterates over the props. this array could be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use a [named slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots)

```
<template>
    <ul class="button-group">
        <li><slot name="buttons"></slot></li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

And than:

```
<vue-button-group class="radius tiny">
    <template slot="buttons">
       <vue-button link="#" styling="tiny bg-aqua">Button 1</vue-button>
       <vue-button link="#" styling="tiny bg-aqua">Button 2</vue-button>
       <vue-button link="#" styling="tiny bg-aqua">Button 3</vue-button>
       <vue-button link="#" styling="tiny bg-aqua">Button 4</vue-button>
   </template>
</vue-button-group>
```

Comment: But wouldn't this render all 4 buttons into the same list item? That's the issue I am having currently.